# Without calling Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") run program

Tags: jdbc

Without load Driver `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` my program 
work is fine... How...?

[image: Coding Picture]

[image: DataBase Picture]

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. Please paste your code into the question directly using the [edit] button. Do not use an image of the code which is hard to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in the [javadoc of DriverManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html)

> The DriverManager methods getConnection and getDrivers have been enhanced to support the Java Standard Edition Service Provider mechanism. JDBC 4.0 Drivers must include the file META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver. This file contains the name of the JDBC drivers implementation of java.sql.Driver. For example, to load the my.sql.Driver class, the META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver file would contain the entry:
>
> ```
> my.sql.Driver
> ```
>
> Applications no longer need to explicitly load JDBC drivers using Class.forName(). Existing programs which currently load JDBC drivers using Class.forName() will continue to work without modification.
>
> When the method getConnection is called, the DriverManager will attempt to locate a suitable driver from amongst those loaded at initialization and those loaded explicitly using the same classloader as the current applet or application.